# Light path node and Emission

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, light, transparency, lighting

I was hoping, is there a way to remove the reflection of the emitting material on the table and still retain the energy from the emission?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not a direct answer but in Cycles, if you select your emitter object, go in the Properties panel > Object > Cycles Settings, you can disable Glossy and it will give the result you want, except it will have the same effect on any other object

Comment: Thanks. The light path node is really strong.